# What is "`CUSTOMER SVC`" in fully spelled out English?

Tags: vocabulary, acronyms, initialisms

It is difficult to use machine translation in order to translate abbreviations from English to Spanish when the words are not spelled correctly.

What is "`CUSTOMER SVC`" in fully spelled out English?

Perhaps there exist dictionaries of standard American abbreviations of English words used in business. If so, I would hope that the dictionary would contain an entry for this abbreviation.

Comment: There may be, well there are, differences between American English and English English :) Similar to the differences in Spanish :)

Comment: I've voted to close this question.  There are thousands of "what is this abbreviation" and they can usually be answered by a dictionary.  I see no reason to add and self-answer more questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

`CUSTOMER SVC` is, most oftenm an abbreviation of `CUSTOMER SERVICE`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain Google Translate can handle this kind of thing pretty well on its own. Out of curiosity, I just typed in "CUSTOMER SVC" (all caps, just as you have it) and got the result "SERVICIO AL CLIENTE." That looks like it should be equivalent, so the abbreviation wasn't a problem.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is a correct answer.  If youbelieve the question is noff-topic, vote to close, do not vote down answers.

Comment: I didn't downvote, @BadZen. Just commented to address what I believe may be a misunderstanding on OP's part. The abbreviated version already gives the same translation output as the full version does, so attempting to compile a set of entries for each abbreviation seems unnecessary.

Comment: @BadZen - the whole thing is bad and needs closing.